# How to get Instance of Class when using Class Decorator

Tags: python, class, instance, decorator

so I'm here to find out where the **C class's Instance** has gone, namely **spam**. we all know, of course, that if we call a method from a class through Instance, Instance i.e. (self) is automatically passed in. so I want to know where self (Instance of C class) gone when calling methodDec. So i can use the **spam** Instance

```
class decorator:
    def __init__(self, func):   
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args):   
         self.func(self,*args)      

class C:
    def method(*a): 
        print(*a)       
    methodDec = decorator(method)

spam=C()
spam.methodDec('x','y','z')
spam.method('x','y','z')
```

the output is

```
>>> <__main__.decorator object at 0x0120A148> x y z
    <__main__.C object at 0x0120A208> x y z
```

Comment: A function supports the descriptor protocol therefore "spam.method" triggers the `__get__` method to return a bound method (holding self) which provides self as first parameter when called. A class does not automatically support this protocol, therefore "spam.methodDec" is just the same as "C.methodDec". See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods

Comment: Thanks sir. indeed I am somewhat surprised by the descriptor and the picture I did above. it seems a mystery to me, so I can only eat it raw what happened, without knowing how it happened. Thank you :)